# @RepositoryRestController - doesn't work in Spring boot 2 (Spring data rest)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm, using **SPRING DATA REST** . I have this controller.

```
org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
@RepositoryRestController
class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/testing")
    fun secured(): String {
        return "Hello world"
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET), value = "/scanners")
    @ResponseBody
    fun getProducers(): ResponseEntity<*> {

        return ResponseEntity.ok<Any>("this is just a tedskljdksjdksjkdsjdkskdst")
    }
}
```

I can't access this endpoint, i'm always getting ***404 NOT FOUND***, when i change to **@RestController** i can hit the route.

Comment: I think this would be the case when you haven't properly included the Controller using `@ComponentScan(basePackages =` in the configuration Main class application. Can you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. If you have users entity, and your endpoint is by default **/users**, if you need to create new endpoint it must be named like this **/users/testing**, in that way you don't get 404 error.

```
@RepositoryRestController
class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/users/testing")
    fun secured(): String {
        return "Hello world"
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET), value = "/scanners")
    @ResponseBody
    fun getProducers(): ResponseEntity<*> {

        return ResponseEntity.ok<Any>("this is just a test")
    }
}
```